# How to vertical center the bounding box to the x-height?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

Hi, all my question is in the title.

Comment: The bounding box extents will vary from font to font. I don't think that what you are trying to do is possible, but it might help if you can expand your question to explain why or what exactly you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: As @Chris points out, this is not possible. Each font has a defined vertical space for ascenders, descenders and leading, the bounding box is defined by that, per font. One possible workaround may be for you to turn on `Use Preview Bounds` in the **Preferences**. However, I'm uncertain if that will assist in whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For area type:

[image]

#### For point text:

1. Select text
2. <kbd>Effect</kbd> > <kbd>Path</kbd> > <kbd>Outline Object</kbd>

[image]

Make sure you toggle on/off <kbd>Use Preview Bounds</kbd>:

[image]

From there, I would suggest reading my answer here:

- [“Correctly” vertically center text in a box](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/74659/10258)

Comment: Thx mhuse, I'll use Effect > Path > Outline Object

Comment: Yah, outline object is pretty useful for alignment purposes. Good question and thanks for the checkmark!